# Issue while connecting to elasticsearch

Tags: stormcrawler

I have been following video blog on Storm Crawler.

I am trying to create a web crawler referring the WIKI and video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMCuWpPh-4A&feature=youtu.be , but I am getting:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received message from unsupported version: [2.0.0] minimal compatible version is: [5.0.0]

I am using following:
Elasticsearch : 5.3.0 version
Storm: 1.0.3 version.

Please help me with what versions are recommended and used by you.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks!
Raj

Comment: And this is response from Julien:
Please use StackOverflow in the future for asking questions such as these.
The video is based on the archetype 1.4 which uses ES 2.x but we've upgraded to ES5 since. Clone the repo, build with mvn clean install and recreate a new project with the archetype again but this time specifying 1.5-SNAPSHOT. This should get you the right dependencies for ES5.

<https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/issues/453#issuecomment-292747073>